# What's the difference between "rock" and "stone"?

Tags: differences, nouns

What's the difference between "rock" and "stone"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A rock is bigger, possibly immovable, you couldn't throw it with one hand, at a pinch you might be able to with two.
[image]

*Above, a Google Image result for "Rock", below, for "Stone"*

[image]

Note that a boulder is probably bigger than a rock<sup>1</sup>.

*Below, a boulder*

[image]

Oh, also note that rocks *and* boulders are made from stone.

*(This answer is mildly [tongue in cheek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue_in_cheek))*

<sup>1</sup> Notable exception: [Uluru/Ayre's Rock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uluru).

Comment: haha am i the only one that finds the first and last pictures just funny in this context?

Comment: @Claudiu, to be honest I don't find them funny. Why?

Comment: I'm with @Bruno Rothgiesser: I don't know why @Benjol has labeled his answer as tongue-in-cheek, and I don't know why the pictures might be funny. If there's a joke in here somewhere, it's hiding from me.

Comment: It's just like... imagine someone asks "Hey what is the difference between a stone and a rock?" then you say "a rock is bigger" and slam down a huge rock in front of him, saying "see?". i actually didn't realize he labeled his answer tongue in cheek until you pointed it out, i just smiled. also just the way it's positioned in that first picture.. its so unremarkable. literally like "Here's a rock."

Comment: @Martha, @Bruno, tongue in cheek because these are hand-waving approximations, not much better than 'how long is a piece of string'. Also, there is a pinch of 'ask a silly question...'. Also, so many answers here use Google Search as proof, I thought it was mildly funny to use Google *Image* search for once.

Comment: "Steel + Stone: soft opening" A building materials store (named Steel + Stone) at our place ran this sign during their soft opening. Couldn't resist sharing this, since we're talking about rocks and stones :)

Comment: As a wise philosopher once said, "But can ye not also make bridges out of stone?" It would seem he intends stones to be fairly large.

Comment: **Stone** is of Germanic origin, **rock** is of Romance origin.  That's the real difference.  English has many synonyms due to words from different sources.

Comment: There's also [living rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-cut_architecture), which is different again.

Comment: @TRiG Dr. Living Stone, I presume?

Answer (score 8):

Generally, usage has made the two words completely interchangeable.  However, I would use stone to refer to the stuff from which rocks are made.

- His house is made of stone.

is probably better than

- His house is made of rock.

But

- He built his house out of stones.

is as acceptable as

- He built his house out of rocks.

Comment: Stone tends to be the human altered (cut or treated) substance or building material - rock is the material in a natural context more often. eg: "Rock strata" in mineralogy and hydrology, but dressed stone building (rather than hewn rock or cut rock building). Interesting patterns of use...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I would ever refer to "a rock". To me, "rock" is a substance - I recognise "a rock" but think of it as a principally American word.
I do talk about "a stone" as well as "stone" - "stone" is the substance which has been, or may be, used for building.

Comment: so it was Americans who named *the Rock of Gibraltar*?