# What's the difference between a "fen" and a "dale"?

Tags: differences, nouns

What's the difference between a *fen* and a *dale*?  Are these words used precisely at all?

My question comes from Kipling’s poem [*The Spirit of England*](http://books.google.com/books?id=1l6gAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22fen%20and%20dale%22&pg=PA49#v=onepage&q=%22fen%20and%20dale%22&f=false); if you'll notice, each couplet, *plain* and *hill*, *towns* and *downs* seem to be opposing, and I was wondering if that were true for *woodland* and *fen* and *dale*.

> I summon to battle from plain and hill,
>   From woodland and fen and dale,
>   From my reeking towns and greyhound downs
>   My men to be cast in the scale.

Comment: Off Topic: Are you on a questions rampage? :D

Comment: These are not even slightly similar.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From Wikipedia regarding **[dale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dale)**:

> A dale is a valley. The word dale comes from Old English dael and is related to Old Norse dalr.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Dale%2C_Pembrokeshire.jpg/800px-Dale%2C_Pembrokeshire.jpg))</sub>

And **[fen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fen)**:

> A fen is a type of wetland fed by mineral-rich surface water or groundwater.
>
> Fens are characterised by their water
>   chemistry, which is neutral or
>   alkaline, with relatively high
>   dissolved mineral levels but few other
>   plant nutrients. They support a wide
>   range of animals and plants, many of
>   which are tall marsh plants growing
>   closely together.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Haha, answers in pictures, [guaranteed](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6886/what-do-you-call-a-bunch-of-garlic-when-you-dont-remove-the-cloves/6893#6893) [hit](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5931/whats-the-difference-between-rock-and-stone/5933#5933) :)

Comment: Often worth a thousand words. ;)

Comment: +1 not for the pictures, but for the etymology.  Background information is always good.

Comment: Arguably, on a site dedicated to linguistic expression, resorting to images is a cop-out. :)

Answer (score 10):

They are both related to geography but have different meanings and are also somewhat geographically specific.

A *[fen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fen)* is a type of wetland.  In Eastern England there is an area known as *The Fens* that although now largely drained typified this sort of geographical feature.

*Dale* means *valley* and is part of many place names, mostly in the North of Britain.  The *Yorkshire Dales* is an upland region in Northern England.

Comment: Everyone said I was daft to build a castle on a swamp, but I built in all the same, just to show them. It sank into the swamp. So I built a second one. That sank into the swamp. So I built a third. That burned down, fell over, then sank into the swamp.

Answer (score 5):

A *fen* is wetland, but it doen't have to be particularly lower than the surrounding land. A *dale* is a valley, and it doesn't have to be wet.